# How can i choose next li within a each loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to make a Slider with 5 boxes when the each box is animating the middle one gets bigger but i couldn't make that happen.

Here is a sample code:

```
$(".mNext").click(function () {
  var boxCurrent = $(".mBox.current").data("index"),
      dir = $(".mBox:first").data("index");
  if (boxCurrent == boxLength) {
      goFirstBox();
  }
  $(".mBox").each(function (i) {
      var $item = $(this);
      $item.stop().animate({
          left: (dir === 1) ? '-=' + "170" + 'px' : '+=' + "170" + 'px'
      }, 600);
      if ($item.hasClass("mBig")) {

          $(this).removeClass("mBig");
          $(this).find("li:first").addClass("maBig");
      }
  });
```

And if you want JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/theOne623/hXBQ9/

Comment: Why do you write a function yourself? There are a lot of plugins that do what you try to achieve :-)

Comment: @Pieter: Why use someone elses code when you can learn something doing things yourself?

Comment: @Pieter: can you think of a better way to learn, than by trying?

Comment: @Lee My thoughts exactly.

Comment: If you want to learn something by doing yourself, try to find existing plugins and learn from them. It's not useful to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: well yeah there are but i couldnt find the right one for myself. there are only with one box moving not the all 5.

Comment: I beg to differ. Why break your head over something that somebody has already broken their head on and when you can easily get it and see how they did it?

Comment: It was just an open question, not an personal attack ;-) Back to the question, @theOne: maybe this plugin can help you? (http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/)

Comment: @Pieter sorry if i sound cranky :) and thanks for your suggest i'll figure it out ;)

Comment: It was a reaction on Lee and F4r-20, not on you :-) OK, good luck! If you're still having troubles, edit your question with the code you've tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to the next `li` by calling

```
$(this).next();
```

The problem with your fiddle is you are adding the class `mBig` to the next `li` so when the next element is found in the `each` loop, it also finds it, removes it and adds it to the next.

Instead keep a reference to the new `li` and add the class after the `each` loop has finished.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dh8uB/